# How to wait block confirmations after transfer

Tags: javascript, hardhat

```
fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer);
```

```
it("Check fund and withdraw", async function () {
              await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue });
              await fundMe.withdraw({ gasLimit: 100000 });
              const finalBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                  fundMe.address
              );
              assert.equal(finalBalance.toString(), "0");
          });
```

I can't figure it out how to wait(x) block confirmation before:

```
const finalBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                  fundMe.address
              );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a sudden enlightenment :) I hope it helps someone else

```
it("Check fund and withdraw", async function () {
              await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue });
              const waiter = await fundMe.withdraw({
                  gasLimit: 100000,
              });
              await waiter.wait(1);
              const finalBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                  fundMe.address
              );
```